# "Invalid use of '\' in replacement text" with non-interactive calls

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, interactive

It seems that `replace-regexp` has a different behavior if called interactively and not, but I do not understand why, and how to get the wanted behavior.

What I want is the non-interactive equivalent of:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET foo1 RET foo\#
```

which, if called on buffer

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
```

creates

```
foo0
foo1
foo2
```

Now, non-interactively, the naive

```
(replace-regexp "foo1" "foo\\#")
```

yields

```
"Invalid use of '\' in replacement text"
```

The same happens with

```
(funcall-interactive "foo1" "foo\\#")
```

And singling or doubling the backslashes give the expected (unwanted) results:

```
(replace-regexp "foo1" "foo\#")
;; foo#
;; foo#
;; foo#

(replace-regexp "foo1" "foo\\\\#")
;; foo\#
;; foo\#
;; foo\#
```

Of course, running `call-interactively` works, but in my use-case the regexp and replacement string will be crafted by elisp code.

Running a loop searching and replacing would probably work, but is it really the only solution? It seems hard to believe.

Comment: The conversion of the replacement text into lisp code is contained in the interactive specification of `replace-regexp`. It is essentially `(query-replace-compile-replacement "foo\\#" t)` which returns `(replace-eval-replacement concat "foo" (number-to-string replace-count))` (resolved over several function calls). The documentation of `replace-regexp` says quite clearly that `\#` only works in interactive calls and that you should use `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` instead in emacs-lisp code.

Comment: `(query-replace-compile-replacement to-string t)` seems to suit my purposes perfectly. Are there any pitfalls that I don't see yet? And in any case, would you mind turning your comment with its great explanation into an answer?

Comment: You can/should write up an answer yourself and accept it afterwards. `query-replace-compile-replacement` is a documented function from `replace.el`. There are no double-slashes in the name and the code is not marked as internal. Therefore, usage of the function should be safe. Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Credits go to [Tobias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2370/tobias))

`replace-regexp` (and `query-replace-regexp`) have their second read argument malaxed into a suitable form for the elisp call. In particular, in case the replacement string contains elisp forms, it is turned into a quoted elisp expression by the function `query-replace-compile-replacement`.

It is actually written explicitely in the documentation for `query-replace-regexp`... once you know what to look for:

> When using those Lisp features interactively in the replacement
>   text, TO-STRING is actually made a list instead of a string.
>   Use C-x M-: after this command for details.

Anyway, it turns out that replacing `"foo\\#"` with `(query-replace-compile-replacement "foo\#" t) works for my purpose. And the entire call, with elisp-supplied strings and just enough interactivity,

```
(let ((from-string "foo1")
      (to-string "foo\\#"))
   (funcall-interactively #'query-replace-regexp
                          from-string
                          (query-replace-compile-replacement to-string t)))
```

works as intended.

Thanks!