# Elisp expressions in projectile-replace-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, projectile, replace

I need to execute a regular expression with case conversion in a entire project. If I run `query-replace-regexp` in a single file informing `'\([A-Z]+\)'` and `'\,(downcase \1)'`, it works as expected. But when I try that with `projectile-replace-regexp` I get the following error:

```
Invalid use of ‘\’ in replacement text
```

I investigated it a bit and it seems that the elisp expression doesn't work when `query-replace-regexp` is not called interactively, because if I run `M-:` `(replace-regexp "'\\([A-Z_]+'\\)" "'\\,(downcase \\1)")` I also have the error above.

Am I doing something wrong or is this some limitation? If so, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: The doc string of `query-replace-regexp` says "In interactive calls, the replacement text can contain ‘\,’
followed by a Lisp expression.  Each
replacement evaluates that expression to compute the replacement
string.  Inside of that expression, ‘\&’ is a string denoting the
whole match as a string, ‘\N’ for a partial match, ‘\#&’ and ‘\#N’
for the whole or a partial match converted to a number with
‘string-to-number’, and ‘\#’ itself for the number of replacements
done so far (starting with zero)."

Comment: And the doc string of `replace-regexp` says "This function is for interactive use only;
in Lisp code use `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` instead."

Comment: If the projectile command does not allow the `query-replace-regexp` behavior then maybe consider filing an enhancement request with its maintainer.

Comment: @Drew Just filed a [bug report](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1399). I consider it as a bug if a function that has `replace-regexp` in its name and does not behave like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is related to [another question about non-interactive calls of `query-replace-regexp`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31853/2370). If they cannot use `query-replace-read-args` in [`projectile-replace-regexp`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/5bd9db6f4b0a9e1c27136561b134a4d119552cdb/projectile.el#L3389-L3414) they should at least apply `query-replace-compile-replacement` to the `TO` argument of [`tags-query-replace`](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-release/blob/adfd5933358fdf6715423dee8169eb3cd7d982db/lisp/progmodes/etags.el#L1886-L1909).

The following advice of `projectile-replace-regexp` does that for you.

```el
(defun my-tags-query-replace-compile-replacement (fun &rest args)
  "Apply `q-r-compile-replacement' to `tags-query-replace' in FUN with ARGS."
  (cl-letf* ((old-tags-query-replace (symbol-function 'tags-query-replace))
         ((symbol-function 'tags-query-replace)
          (lambda (from to &rest other-args)
        (apply old-tags-query-replace
               from
               (query-replace-compile-replacement to t)
               other-args))))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'projectile-replace-regexp :around #'my-tags-query-replace-compile-replacement)
```

DISCLAIMER: Note that I do not have `projectile` installed. So I cannot test the code above. Please test it and report back the test results.

NOTE: I already filed a bug-report for the problem that [`projectile-replace-regexp` does not have the interactive features of `replace-regexp`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1399).

Comment: It worked! Very nice solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jesse Do you have the possibility to comment on [the bug report](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1399)? It would be good to have an acknowledgement of the bug by a real `projectile`-user. This should be easy if you already have a github account. Ignore that comment if you do not have such an account.

Comment: Sure, no problem